# Difference between "bdo" element and other elements with "dir" attribute?

Tags: html, bidirectional

What is the difference between using `bdo`

```
<bdo dir="rtl">CIBARA english EMOS</bdo>
```

and using most tags with `dir` attribute like

```
<span dir="rtl">CIBARA english EMOS</span>
```

I know this question is similar to [should i always use bdo for text direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163756/should-i-always-use-bdo-for-text-direction), but I still do not understand why the use of the `dir` attribute is "adequate" and `bdo` is not needed.

Doesn't the `dir` attribute "override the inherent directionality of letters" anyway? In which instances must I use `bdo`?

Comment: This will help you understand better: **( http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2 )**. Read carefully until end. You would have understood it clearly, by the time you reach this line: "*... The BDO element should be used in scenarios where absolute control over sequence order is required (e.g., multi-language part numbers).*"

Comment: In a nutshell, `bdo` is for the serious stuff and for the general use `dir` works well

Answer (score 3):

Using -

```
<span dir="rtl">CIBARA english EMOS</span>
```

Styles applied in Chrome:

```
span[Attributes Style] {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
}
```

Using -

```
<bdo dir="rtl">CIBARA english EMOS</bdo>
```

Styles applied in Chrome:

```
bdo[Attributes Style] {
    direction: rtl;
}

bdo {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

So, with the use of `<bdo>` element, the default value `bidi-override` is always applied in most browsers and it should work as intended. The use of attribute `dir` does not seem to be adequate. See below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This paragraph will go left-to-right.</p>  
<p><span dir="rtl">This paragraph will go right-to-left.</span></p>
<p><bdo dir="rtl">This paragraph will go right-to-left.</bdo></p>  

</body>
</html>
```